# convergence of $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} } $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  }$ converges. How can I do that?

I have simplified that into:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  } = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+k}}  } < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k^2+k}  }$

If I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k^2+k}  }$ converges
then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  }$ must converge, right?

How can I go on ?

I have tried the quotient criterium which gives me equals $1$. So it is not very helpful here.

Comment: I think it's divergent.

Comment: The inequality is incorrect, it should be the other way around.

Comment: "I want to prove that ... converges" Maybe you want this but this will be difficult to achieve since the series diverges.

Comment: How did you obtain this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  } > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+1)}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k+1}  }$$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  } > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k+1}  }$$

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k+1}  }$ diverges, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  }$ diverges too.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}} = \frac{1}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k}}} > \frac{1}{k}$$

meaning you will have fairly little luck in proving convergence...

---

Also, you are very very wrong in saying

> If I show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{k^2+k}  }$ converges
>   then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}  }$ must converge, right?

The answer to that question is **NO**. Similarly, you can show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$$ converges, but $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k$$**does not**.

Comment: Your first inequality goes the wrong way...

Answer (score 1):

$a_k:= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)^2}} \lt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}.$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$  is divergent , harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

With *equvalents*:

$\sqrt{k(k+1)}\sim_\infty\sqrt{k^2}=k$, so
$\;\dfrac 1{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}\sim_\infty\frac 1k,\; $
and the *harmonic series* diverges.